# Discord.py bot, category isn't being created at the required position

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

botToken = "*"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '*')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm ready!")

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    a = await ctx.guild.create_category("TEST", position=0)
    a.position = 0

client.run(botToken)
```

**position= int** and **channel.position = int** ain't working..
Haven't found any question related to my problem, gave bot Administrator permissions at https://discord.com/developers/applications and got the link let him in my server, create a role with everything allowed and gave him the role, didn't work..
**create_text_channel** and **create_voice_channel** nothing changes, The channels are being set as if I didn't assign a position to them.

[Picture showing where the category position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Su4E.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because there's no position 0, the first position is always 1

```py
category = await ctx.guild.create_category("TEST", position=1)
```

If it still creates the category in another position you can manually edit it:

```
await category.edit(position=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've actually seen a question where someone answered as position starts with 0, and it does! For some reasons, first 3-4 times I used the first method it worked, although it stopped working for some reasons, but the second method worked while using position=0! **Thanks a lot!**

Comment: sure, remember to accept the answer if it helped.